# Почему мне выдаёт следующую ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.10

Я запускаю код через `torch.hub.load`, он мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\79604\Desktop\VoiceControl\speak.py", line 8, in <module>
model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 404, in load
model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 433, in _load_local
model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\79604/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 88, in silero_tts
model = imp.load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\package\package_importer.py", line 254, in load_pickle     
result = unpickler.load()
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pickle.py", line 1213, in load
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pickle.py", line 1254, in load_binpersid
self.append(self.persistent_load(pid))
File "C:\Users\79604\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_script.py", line 351, in unpackage_script_module      
cpp_module = torch._C._import_ir_module_from_package(RuntimeError: Unknown qengine`
```

Пробую через `silero` и выдаёт следующее:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\79604\Desktop\VoiceControl\speak.py", line 9, in <module>
model, example_text = silero(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models', TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Вот код:
С `silero`:

```
import torch
import silero

device = torch.device('cpu')
torch.set_num_threads(4)
speaker = 'xenia'  # 'aidar', 'baya', 'kseniya', 'xenia', 'random'
sample_rate = 48000  # 8000, 24000, 48000
put_accent = True
put_yo = True

model, example_text = silero(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language='ru',
                                     speaker='ru_v3')
model.to(device)
audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

С `torch`:

```
import torch

device = torch.device('cpu')
torch.set_num_threads(4)
speaker = 'xenia'  # 'aidar', 'baya', 'kseniya', 'xenia', 'random'
sample_rate = 48000  # 8000, 24000, 48000
put_accent = True
put_yo = True

model, example_text = torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                     model='silero_tts',
                                     language='ru',
                                     speaker='ru_v3')
model.to(device)
audio = model.apply_tts(text=example_text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate)
```

Как мне решить хоть одну из этих проблем?

И да, я пробовал переустанавливать `torch`, переустанавливать его через -U, пробовал делать следующие вещи: `from silero import silero` и `silero.silero`

Comment: Вот этот пример кода пробовали https://github.com/snakers4/silero-models#installation-and-basics ? Заменить то, что #before на то что #after

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное! Я решил проблему

Comment: Я просто скопировал с этой документации код, добавил `silero_tts` , `sounddevise` и `time`, плюсом подрубил `put_accent` и `put_yo` к `audio` и у меня всё заработало!

Comment: Вот как полезно читать документацию :)  Если не лениво, оформите сами ответ на вопрос с тем кодом, который у вас получился.